# input validation on the same textbox email and password

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to implement username and email validation on the same textbox in my login.
Basically I would like in the same textbox to validate me both the username and the email, however when I try to enter an email inside it tells me invalid username, but really it should tell me invalid email, I also made a regex, I post my code because I can't figure out...

```
  private void button15_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) // Enter button that refers to the keypad button I created for login

    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_UserName.Text))
        {

            txt_UserName.Enabled = true;
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label6.Text = "Username is empty";
            txt_UserName.Focus();

        }
        else
        {

           txt_UserName.Enabled = true;
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            label6.Text = "Username is acceptable";
            txt_Password.Focus();



        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_Password.Text))
        {

            txt_Password.Enabled = true;
            txt_userName.Enabled = false;
            label7.Text = "Password is Empty";
            label7.ForeColor = Color.Red;


        }

        else
        {
            //txt_userName.Enabled = true;
            txt_Password.Enabled = true;
            label7.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            label7.Text = "Password is acceptable";
            txt_Password.Focus();

        }

        if (txt_UserName.Text.Length > 9)
        {
            txt_Password.Enabled = false;
            txt_UserName.Enabled = true;
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label6.Text = "Username is not valid";
            txt_UserName.Focus();

        }

        if (txt_Password.Text.Length > 9)
        {
            txt_Password.Enabled = true;
            txt_UserName.Enabled = false;
            label7.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label7.Text = "Password is not valid";
            txt_Password.Focus();


            if (txt_UserName.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                // txt_UserName.Enabled = true;
                txt_Password.Enabled = true;
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label6.Text = "Username is Empty";
                txt_UserName.Focus();
            }



            string email = txt_UserName.Text;
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-za-za-z]{2,3})+$");
            Match match = regex.Match(email);


            if (match.Success)
            {
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                label6.Text = "The email is correct";
                txt_Password.Enabled = true;
                txt_Password.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label6.Text = "The email is incorrect";
                txt_UserName.Enabled = true;
                txt_Password.Enabled = false;
                txt_UserName.Focus();
            }
```

Comment: You didn't post the entire click handler, but it looks like the code that checks the email with the regex is INSIDE the block that checks if the password is greater than 9 chars long: `if (txt_Password.Text.Length > 9)`. Move it out of that block.

Comment: Unrelated: I'd recommend to use one of `string.IsNullOrEmpty( string )` or `string.IsNullOrWhitespace( string )` instead of `string == string.Empty`.